# Angular 4 - On change component object

Tags: angular, select, listener, onchange, dropdown

I have a component with some dropdowns. Each dropdown is populated by an array (loaded via rest services) and sometimes these arrays could be updated.
Is there a way to call a function when these arrays changes?
Such as a listener on a variable that when is reassigned I do somethings.

Thanks 
Fabrizio

Comment: how are they updated exactly ? i think  you are surely calling the rest service to reload your data , are you ?

Comment: If you can post the way you are updating the data of your dropdown , we might be able to help

Comment: I'm calling the rest service and update the array. This array will populate the "option" field of a dropdown `this.gameService.getGameProviders().subscribe(data => {
      this.providers = this.emptyMapItem.concat(data.filter(value => value.filter === this.game.groupId));
    }, error => console.error(error));`

Answer (score 0):

If dropdowns are separate components and arrays are passed to them, you can use `OnChanges`. `ngOnChanges` function is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  prop: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

There is no Angular equivalent to AngularJs' `$watch`.

Alternatively, you can call desired function after success data update when you call REST API.